# What challenges can data science help with in small businesses

Tags: data-visualization, data-mining, business-intelligence

Data science can solve/help with many challenges.

But it usually looked upon as something for multi-million dollar corporations.

I'm looking for examples of challenges data science helped with in small/medium businesses.

**EDIT**
I am looking at this from a perspective of: "If I am a restaurant owner, yoga studio owner, dentist, etc., how can it help me?"

Comment: Besides in business, machine learning is applied on a very wide range of topics in academic research. I would assume there are actually a plenty of (more or less) innovative new prototype devices etc. (hence startups) that use ML as some part of it.

Comment: is this for some class?

Comment: Can you define data science ?

Comment: No, this is not for a class. Look at my previous questions.

Comment: Data science/machine learning - by that I mean tools that can bring greater understanding, and/or perform tasks that are not viable to do by hand.

Comment: Maybe this question fits better on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

Small business can also take advantage of data science. If you are a restaurant owner and you want to advertise you restaurant via e.g. Groupon, you can use data science to analyze Groupon users and find your targeted customs. Thus, your advertisement will only be shown to people who are likely to come to your restaurant.

By the way, I've read several articles from data science central about the same topic that you concern.

http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/affinity-analysis-cost-effective-data-science-for-smaller-banks-a

http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/big-data-analytics-and-business-intelligence-for-better-customer

There are many more related articles on data science central.